# Cannot access Mongodb Atlas using my PC IP address

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose, whitelist

I'm getting the following error

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to ****cluster******** closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CITY TECH\Documents\Projects\Cliserve\cliserve-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:388:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

After adding my IP address to the MongoDB Atlas whitelist for privacy reasons.

I input my IP address by clicking the `Add you IP address`- it's same as the https://whatismyipaddress.com/ result-

> I turned off the firewall and not proxy server exists

Any Idea why this error occurred?

Comment: Which operation produces this error?

Comment: @Oleg While I'm trying to connect to MongoDB through in an express app

Comment: "TransientTransactionError" is supposed to be produced when an operation fails, not when a client first connects to deployment.

Comment: I removed my IP address from the whitelist and it's working without any error, so the problem is related to the IP address don't know why isn't allow my PC to access the database @Oleg

Comment: i am having same issue,  connection is only  successful when i provide access from anywhere in mongodb atlas ip whitelist